# Need advice on unit testing

Tags: unit-testing

I am just starting to learn unit testing and I think it's a really good tool which I want to start using for all my projects, however I'm still not sure how to test some things.
As an example I am implementing a queue and one of the methods it has is AddNode, I also have a mock object representing the Node in the queue, after writing the method I don't know what I should test for. The method is void so I can't test for a return value, maybe I should test for out of mamory exception or some other exception ? or maybe there is no need to do any testing in this case.

Comment: "As an example I am implementing a queue". Why? Is there no queue available in a standard or optional library that fits the bill? The best way to improve test coverage is to minimize the amount of code you need to maintain yourself.

Answer (score 1):

For AddNode you could be testing the following:

- queue is not empty afterwards
- size has increased by one
- if the queue checks for duplication, that the size has not increased after adding a duplicate
- a roundtrip: new Queue, addNode, getNode returns the same Node again
- if the queue checks for invalid objects (no nulls, wrong node type or something), that there is an exception when you try to add these things.

Note that some of these tests do not test AddNode in isolation (they also need to call other methods). That is not a problem. You are unit-testing the class, not individual methods.

Comment: "You are unit-testing the class, not individual methods". I agree with you but I thought I should build it step by step, write a method then test it, write another then test it, an so on until I'll  have the complete class completely tested.

Comment: It is a good approach to have a test method for every public method in the class. However, you can still call other methods in order to assert the expected behaviour. As an aside, you cannot be sure that the class is completely tested by just making sure that all methods have been called at least once. You also need meaningful assertions for all possible cases/code paths.

Comment: I am not doing just one test per method, I try to cover every possibility of things going wrong.